# Getting the pixel coordinates in ms-paint by c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have [this pic](http://amyrh.persiangig.com/image/xyCoordinates.png), and i need when i click(left click mouse) on every pic's pixel in ms-paint, write pixel's x and y coordinates of image in text file.

Comment: What are you trying to do, what have you tried, and what problem are you having?

Comment: writing pixel's x and y coordinates by c# when you clicked on pic's pixel in ms-paint.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easier to make a small program that opens and displays the image. Then you can capture the click events on the image controller and get the coordinates from the click event.
Writing the coordinates to file should then be relatively easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it on `Paint`. But If you want to get color from which pixel you want and you can change it using with [`Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) class;

```
Bitmap bmpimage = new Bitmap("yourfilename");
//to get the pixel color of the image
Color c = bmpimage.GetPixel(50,50);
//to set the color of the pixel
bmpimage.SetPixel(50, 50, Color.Yellow);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will pretend that this is question is not from your little brother. anyway, here I go. What you are looking at in that pic is just an image, you cannot change the text inside of an image unless you overlay that zone with a new background and text. Regarding the coordinates, if you are using Windows Forms, you can respond to an event called MouseMove that will give you the coordinates as X and Y from your respective container object.

You could get the coordinates and then overlay the image with the new values, but probably you need to read A LOT more about programming to understand why your question is kinda complicated.

Comment: You didn't understand my mean. i want getting pic's x, y coordinates of image in ms-paint.